# connecting shopify Android app: "Add your shop credentials to a shop.properties file in the main app folder"

Tags: android, shopify

I'm trying to build an app for my store.
downloaded the sample app from github (mobile-buy-sdk-android)
but when I try to run it it gives this error and crashes:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.shopify.sample, PID: 4157
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.shopify.sample.application.SampleApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
>                                                                       Add your shop credentials to a shop.properties file in the main app folder (e.g. 'app/shop.properties'). Include these keys:
>                                                                           SHOP_DOMAIN=.myshopify.com
>                                                                           API_KEY=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
>                                                                     You must populate the 'APP_ID' entry in app/shop.properties
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4559)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
>                                                                       Add your shop credentials to a shop.properties file in the main app folder (e.g. 'app/shop.properties'). Include these keys:
>                                                                           SHOP_DOMAIN=.myshopify.com
>                                                                           API_KEY=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
>                                                                     You must populate the 'APP_ID' entry in app/shop.properties
>                                                                         at com.shopify.sample.application.SampleApplication.initializeBuyClient(SampleApplication.java:125)
>                                                                         at com.shopify.sample.application.SampleApplication.onCreate(SampleApplication.java:109)
>                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4556)

Answer (score 0):

Please, read carefully debug log. The answer is there:

> Add your shop credentials to a shop.properties file in the main app
>   folder (e.g. 'app/shop.properties'). Include these keys:
>   SHOP_DOMAIN=.myshopify.com API_KEY=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
>   You must populate the 'APP_ID' entry in app/shop.properties at

Comment: I tried to add shop.properties in the same directory, and every other directory but nothing changed

Comment: $PROJECT_DIR/app/shop.properties. You should add it here. And the second part is API_KEY and APP_ID.

Comment: there is no folder called "app" so I created one. but still the same error. Closed the project and tried again, nothing new. this is getting frustrating :(

Comment: Ooook. Let's make it easier. I suppose you are trying to build sample module from sdk. So open build.gradle file of this module and starting from line 53 until line 64 fulfil values of shopDomain, apiKey, appId, androidPayPublicKey

Answer (score 0):

Their sample app comment is slightly out of date.  The location you need to put the shop.properties file is:

```
/MobileBuy/sample/shop.properties
```

You need to put the API key / domain in

```
SHOP_DOMAIN=YOURSHOP.myshopify.com
API_KEY=<your-api-key>
```

If you are still having problems, then just modify the SampleApplication.java and change the lines t

```
String shopUrl = BuildConfig.SHOP_DOMAIN;
String shopifyApiKey = BuildConfig.API_KEY;
```